# Python MIME adding angle bracket before 'From' in body

Tags: python, mime

I'm stuck with some really weird glitch with Python MIME library. For some reason, when the message contains the string `From something`, printing it as a string produces `>From something`.

I wrote this minimal test case that shows the problematic:

```
from email import charset
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

charset.add_charset('utf-8', charset.SHORTEST)

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = 'test@test.com'
msg.attach(MIMEText('From whatever', "plain", "utf-8"))

print msg.as_string()
```

The output I get is the following:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============1971947716=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: test@test.com

--===============1971947716==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

>From whatever
--===============1971947716==--
```

Apparently this is caused by the `add_charset` call, but I don't see how this can cause an issue that is completely unrelated to UTF8 and charsets.

Comment: What Python version are you using? I can't reproduce this with either Python 2.7 or 3.3 - the text part gets encoded (properly) with `base64` for me, not `7bit`.

Comment: Can you try this: `import email` `text = MIMEText('From whatever', "plain", "utf-8")` `email.encoders.encode_base64(text)` `msg.attach(text)` `print msg.as_string()` (I omitted the rest of your code)

Comment: With the edit I am now able to re-create this with 2.7.5 but am unable to re-create with 3.4 (in 3.4 it looks fine with "From whatever")

Comment: @LukasGraf, I was running the script within the app environment and the problem didn't reproduce in a normal Python shell. I just edited the question.

Comment: Well yeah, with your edit you're now manually mangling the charset. See the [`email.charset.CHARSET`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0ba6ebd90b9d/Lib/email/charset.py#l62) map for the defaults. In the [`Charset`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0ba6ebd90b9d/Lib/email/charset.py#l185) class there is a specific comment that says *"Charset.SHORTEST is not allowed for body_encoding"*.

Comment: I can't really say for sure why and how this behavior is caused by your apparently unsupported (invalid?) charset definition, but it seems to somehow trigger the `From` mangling "feature": See the [`mangle_from` keyword argument to `Generator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.generator.html#email.generator.Generator)

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with encoding, and it is different between Python 2.7 and Python 3.4. Python 3.4 does not exhibit the problem.

In python 2.7 :

```
print MIMEText('From foo')
```

gives

```
From nobody Wed Jul 02 12:17:18 2014
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

>From foo
```

I think the cause is that in traditional mbox format, a line beginning with `From` (not `From:` which denotes a header) is a marker for the begin of a new message (still true in FreeBSD 9 at least). And mailers used to escape it as `>From foo`. I suppose email module does so for compatibility in 2.7